# Download image from image url and showing in Image control in asp.net with C#

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem that I want to show an image in Image control by downloading image from Image url, but I don't know how to do that? Please suggest me right solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you simply use <asp:Image ImageUrl="http://urltoimage.com" runat="server"/> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, so if this is not a solution to your issue please disregard this answer.

I assume what you mean is that you wish to download an image from a URL in the codebehind, store the 
image locally and serve this image to the browser.

To do this you can use the following:

**Markup**

```
<asp:Image ID="image1" runat="server" />
```

**CodeBehind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string imageName = "downloaded-image.png";
        string imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~\Images"), imageName);
        string imageUrl = "https://encrypted.google.com/images/logos/ssl_logo.png";

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFile(imageUrl, imagePath);

        image1.ImageUrl = string.Format(@"~\Images\{0}", imageName);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.